Triggering an uncaught error synchronously while executing a chain of callbacks, without preventing execution of subsequent callbacks
Context:
When executing callbacks that were added with addEventListener, the browser seemingly has a way of executing the callbacks in order, and synchronously triggering an uncaught error if one fails, without disrupting/preventing the subsequent handlers from being executed.
For example, executing this code:


let button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = 'Click';
document.body.append(button);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('1st listener');
  throw new Error('error');
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('2nd listener');
});

console.log("Before click");
button.click();
console.log("After click");



results in these logs:
Before click
1st listener
Uncaught Error: error
2nd listener
After click

The key point here is that the error occurs between the two listeners.
Question:
I'm wondering how to emulate this behavior with my own addEventListener-like framework (and yep, I would just extend EventTarget if I could). Here's some example code to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:


let callbacks = [
  () => { console.log('1st listener'); throw new Error("error"); },
  () => { console.log('2nd listener') },
];

function triggerHandlers() {
  for(let cb of callbacks) {
    try {
      cb();
    } catch(e) { 
      console.error(e); // how to *synchronously* trigger an uncaught error here without interrupting the for loop?
    }
  }
}

console.log("Before click");
triggerHandlers();
console.log("After click");



Possible Solutions:

Maybe using a finally block which recursively calls the function, instead of a for loop? This seems a bit hacky though. I'm hoping there's a more straightforward approach that doesn't require recursion.
Using the built-in EventTarget to side-step the problem. This isn't really a viable solution in my case, except perhaps as a "hacky" solution that uses it "surgically" within the codebase to emulate the above behavior (i.e. not using it in the way it's supposed to be used).

Non-Solutions:

Rethrowing the error via something like setTimeout(()=>throw e, 0) (or equivalent) does not work, since it's not synchronous.


Have you considered callbacks.forEach(queueMicrotask)?

@Unmitigated Hmm that executes all the listeners after the After click line has been logged, but if this is what the browser effectively does on button click (i.e. button click adds a task to event queue rather than synchronously executing a function like in my code example), then I think this is a viable answer.
@Yogi, the short answer is "it's complicated". The slightly longer answer is that it's part of a dev tool where I don't have control over the "userland" code, and I need to emulate the behavior of addEventListener as closely as possible to avoid breaking said userland code.
